# Keep zoom scale after device rotation

Tags: ios, size, zooming, scrollview

I am using viewForZoomingInScrollView to zoom my view in and out. But after I rotate the device the original size pops back. How can I keep the last size after rotation?

Also, I would like to have a zoom button in addition to pinching. Is there a way to trigger zoom with an action and snap to a certain scale? Let's say only 0.5 and 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

Put it in the header